# Combining awk and csum to hash a field

Tags: unix, awk, md5, delimiter

I have pipe-delimited text files that requires an MD5 hash of a particular field, or set of fields.  Because I'm on AIX and have to use the csum function, I don't think I can simply pass the file and a hashing function to awk to do it in one fell swoop.

So I'm writing a script that reads through each line, passes the to-be-hashed field to csum, then drops the result back in as a replacement via a gsub.  99% of the time it seems to work OK, but sometimes something goes afoul because the gsub replaces something it shouldn't.

```
#!/bin/ksh
rm $2 #Get rid of output file
while read line; do #loop through each line
MYFIELD=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "|" -f 6); #push the 6th field into a var
MYHASH=$(echo $MYFIELD | csum -h MD5 -); #csum will hash a string only on the stdin
echo $line | sed -e "s/$MYFIELD/${MYHASH}/g" >> $2 #gsub replaces, but not always what we want
done < $1 #read in the input file
```

I think instead I could use awk to update the field.  But it's beyond me how to do that one line at a time.  Ideally I would like to have a script that would allow me to pass two mandatory parameters (infile and outfile) and then any number of field positions that would get hashed and replaced.  A la

```
foo infile.txt outfile.txt 2 6 12
```

Which would read in infile.txt, hash fields 2, 6, and 12, and write out to outfile.txt.
Your suggestions would be most appreciated

Comment: Have you tried printing the `sed` line to see if the parameters substitution is done properly? Somethink like `echo "$line \| sed -e \"s/$MYFIELD/${MYHASH}/g"`

Comment: @fedorqui the substitution seems to work fine most of the time.  Where it breaks down is when the field to be hashed contains a set of characters that match another field that I don't want hashed.  E.g., donthashit|foo1|bar1|foo2|bar2|hashit will hash field 6 as it should, but sed sees hashit in both the first field and the last and replaces both.  That's a problem since I only want it manipulating field 6.

Comment: If you indicate `/g` it will change it every time it is found. Do you have any pattern to distinguish them?

Comment: I don't for certain know that I do, except that I believe in most (maybe all?) cases the conflict would be with the first field.  Since the first field does not have a pipe immediately before it, I could make sure that I'm replacing only strings that begin with a pipe.  Is that were you're driving to?

Comment: After some testing I think I got it with `awk`. Please see answer below. This way we can replace just the field we want (6th in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing it with `awk`?

Instead of

```
echo $line | sed -e "s/$MYFIELD/${MYHASH}/g" >> $2 #gsub replaces, but not always what we want
```

You can use

```
old=$MYFIELD; new=$MYHASH; echo $line | awk -F"|" -v o="$old" -v n="$new" '{OFS=FS} sub(o, n, $6) {print}' >> $2
```

Basically what we do is:

- `old=$MYFIELD; new=$MYHASH` We assign the parameters to be *sent* to `awk`.
- `echo $line` We output the line so that awk can get it.

In awk,

- `-F"|"` define `|` as field separator.
- `-v o="$old"` and `-v n="$new"` let awk work with variables `$old` and `$new` naming them `o` and `n` respectively.
- `{OFS=FS}` - define the delimiter between fields. It could also be `OFS="|"`, but this way we indicate `awk` to use the same we defined on `-F="|"`. It is more flexible to keep the field separator in case it changes.
- `sub(o, n, $6)` replaces the text on variable `o` (that is, `$MYFIELD`) with text on variable `v` (that is, `$MYHASH`), but **just** on field 6.
- `print` the whole line with substituted text

This worked for me in the example you gave on comments:

```
old="hashit"; new="WE_DID"; echo "donthashit|foo1|bar1|foo2|bar2|hashit" | awk -F"|" -v o="$old" -v n="$new" '{OFS=FS} sub(o,n,$6) {print}'
donthashit|foo1|bar1|foo2|bar2|WE_DID
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**
I [found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485096/array-length-in-ksh-always-return-1-and-why-array-is-not-lines) to pass variables to awk easily: `-v o=${variable_name}`

This way, the solution can be:

```
echo $line | awk -F"|" -v o=${MYFIELD} -v n=${MYHASH} '{OFS=FS} sub(o, n, $6) {print}' >> $2
```

Comment: Nice, looking pretty good.  Your explanation is especially helpful.    However the delimiters aren't preserved; spaces appear to have been substituted.  I shall tinker with it a bit

Comment: You are right, @Amw5G, I did not see it before. I just edited my answer to include the answer for it: we need to use `{OFS=FS}` to define the delimiter. Now it should work.

Comment: Excellent @fedorqui , that seems to do it.  Cheers!