# array length in ksh always return 1 and why array is not lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I need to echo information of a process for a UID in ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
read userid
arr=$(ps -elf | nawk -v pattern=${userid} '{if ($3==pattern) print}')
arrlen=${#arr[@]}
echo $arrlen
for f in "${arr[@]}"; do
  echo $f
done
```

arr is an array of process for this UID.
arrlen always equal 1.
Why?
My second question:
I try to echo all elements in arr and output is

```
0 
S  
s157759 
22594   
1   
0  
50 
20  
?  
2:06 
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin
```

instead of

```
 0 S  s157759 22594   1   0  50 20  ?  62628  ? 11:14:06 ?  2:06 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin
```

in one line

I want to create an array with lines, not words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't creating an array; you're creating a string with newline-separated values. Replace

```
arr=$(ps -elf | nawk -v pattern=${userid} '{if ($3==pattern) print}')
```

with

```
arr=( $(ps -elf | nawk -v pattern=${userid} '{if ($3==pattern) print}') )
```

However, this still leaves you with the problem that the array will treat each field of each line from `ps` as a separate element. A better solution is to read directory from `ps` using the `read` built-in:

```
ps -elf | while read -a fields; do
    if [[ ${fields[2]} = $userid ]]; then
      continue
    fi
    echo "${fields[@]}"
done
```